# What is the proper return for this method?

Tags: java, abstract

This is my subclass code for a ship in a asteroids remaking I am making for practice.

```
 package comets;

    public class Ship extends SpaceObject{

    protected double angle;
    protected double speed;
    public Ship(double xPos,double yPos,double xVel,double yVel){
        super(xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel, 10);
    }
    public void accelerate(){
        this.xVelocity+=.1*Math.sin(angle);
        this.yVelocity+=.1*Math.cos(angle);
    }   
    public double getSpeed(){
        return speed=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.xVelocity, 2)+Math.pow(this.yVelocity,2));
    }
    public Shot fire(){
        //need to return a shot
        return null;            
    }   
    public double getAngle(){
        return angle;       
    }
    public void rotateLeft(){
        angle+=.1;
    }

    public void rotateRight(){
        angle-=.1;
    }
   }
```

As you can see I am not sure how to return the public Shot fire() method. I currently have it returning null but I need it to return Shot so that the ship in the game can shoot bullets. Bellow is the shot class where I have the constructor for shot defined.

```
 package comets;

public class Shot extends SpaceObject{

    protected int counter=0;

    public Shot(double xPos,double yPos,double xVel,double yVel){
        super(xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel, 3);
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return counter;     
    }
    public void move(){
        counter++;
        super.move();
     }
   }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: So...what's stopping you from calculating the shot's velocity?

Comment: @DennisMeng I think its already being done by SpaceObject super class `super(xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel, 3);` ... Clarification needed @user2613088

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a shot does not act, it is only acted upon, there should be no need for a Shot to return anything.

```
public void fire(){
    Shot aShot(foo,bar,foobar,foobarbar);
}
```

The only purpose of the fire method is to create an instance of a shot. Because the shot is likely originating from the same location as the Ship, you should just be able to query the attributes of the parent of a shot (I assume it is the ship).

I assume a shot travels forwards even if the ship is traveling backwards, so you will need to get the angle of the ship, and set that to the forward angle of the shot.

Keep in mind, that you will likely have multiple instances of a shot on screen at any one time. In which case you would want to create an arrayList of Shot objects. You would then have another class/method (Game.loop) which iterates over the full list of objects, and advances them forward. 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm

Consider the following UML, taking note that the arrow types may not be correct, and that the constructors are not present.

[image]

In this example the loop method would contain the collision checking, and object advancement. 
loop would also check to see if a player is still alive, and also check every shot in the arrayList to see if there is a collision between a player and a shot.